# Merging different worksheet into one sheet (only specified rows)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I Have multiple worksheets (like 24 in number!). I would like to merge it into single sheet. All the worksheets have similar structure with header.

Glitch: At the end of every worksheet there is one or two rows with data summary

I would like to omit those line and have continues data of all worksheets.

Here is a piece of code which I used to merge it. But it made multiple sheets in single excel file. Is it possible to add some code within this piece of code.

Thanks in advance!

```js
Sub GetSheets()
Path = "C:\path"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.XLSX")
  Do While Filename <> ""
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
       For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
     Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
      
  Next Sheet
     Workbooks(Filename).Close
     Filename = Dir()
  Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Regarding the glitch, please be more specific; is there anything the computer can use to determine that the rows in question are in fact summary rows? Particular cell values etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does following code do:
- Code will copy data from all the sheets of all `.xlsx` files in the specified folder assuming all files have same structure
- Data is copied to sheet name `Output` of active file
- Last row of each sheet is not copied assuming it contains data summary
- Header will be copied from the first copied sheet
- Code will not add sheets to current file

```
Sub GetSheets()
    Dim path As String, fileName As String
    Dim lastRow As Long, rowCntr As Long, lastColumn As Long
    Dim outputWS As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'this is the sheet where all the data will be displyed        
    Set outputWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
    rowCntr = 1

    path = "C:\path" & "\"
    fileName = Dir(path & "*.XLSX")
    Do While fileName <> ""
        Workbooks.Open fileName:=path & fileName, ReadOnly:=True
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            If rowCntr = 1 Then
                'get column count
                lastColumn = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                'copy header
                Range(outputWS.Cells(1, 1), outputWS.Cells(1, lastColumn)).Value = Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, lastColumn)).Value
                rowCntr = rowCntr + 1
            End If
            'get last row with data of each sheet
            lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            'copy data from each sheet to Output sheet
            Range(outputWS.Cells(rowCntr, 1), outputWS.Cells(rowCntr + lastRow - 3, lastColumn)).Value = Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(lastRow - 1, lastColumn)).Value
            rowCntr = rowCntr + lastRow - 2
        Next ws
        Workbooks(fileName).Close
        fileName = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code may be useful for combining sheets.
This will ask to browse for file to combine. Then it will combine all sheets into one sheet named "Combine"

```
Sub Combine()
    Dim openfile As String
    MsgBox "Pls select Input file", vbOKOnly
    openfile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
    Workbooks.OpenText (openfile)

Dim J As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
Sheets(J).Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
Next

Sheets(1).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got them all into your active workbook you could do an additional step to put them on the same sheet.

Not knowing the layout of your data its difficult but if I assume there's always something in A1 and it's all in a large block then you could loop through the sheets and copy something like:

```
Dim i as integer
For i = 1 to ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count    
   Sheets(i).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
   'Paste it into the sheet here below what's already there
Next i
```